# Can't seem to create new python files

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried making three python files, followed similar steps each time (new python file -> name) but the first two were created as normal files (couldn't run a lot of shortcuts like comment and run) and the third file opened as python file. I'm not sure what's causing this so any help is appreciated

[image: screen shot of the files]

The way I created files :

1. [image: selecting the make new python file opt]
2. [image: adding a name - in this case 'calc']
3. [image: the error - not being a python file]

It does seem to be a python file in the explorer but I can't use the shortcuts or run the code which I'm able to do if it creates itself as a normal python file. The way I'm differentiating them is how their icons look at the PyCharm taskbar

[image: image of the file in file explorer]

Comment: Show the way u create the files

Comment: edited my post with images on how I created the files. hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your files are really txt-files.
Check in windows explorer or in finder if the file extension (it might be hidden) is not .txt.
e.g. your calc file is probably called calc.py.txt and not calc.py.

Comment: It does seem to be a python file instead. can't seem to share the image in this comment but I can edit it in the post itself if you would like

Comment: another thing, I tried adding the files again (diff names) with the same process and they seem to come out fine as normal python files. I can't think of a reason why is this happening

Comment: last thing, I deleted the calc file and tried renaming the python file which came out right to 'calc' but as soon as I change it to any other name, it loses the python file icon but renaming it back to what its name was fixes it

Comment: are you looking at it in pycharm or in finder or windows explorer with extensions being visible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like making a python file named 'Calc.py' is not possible.  other names like 'text' are also giving me errors but names like'calculator' works just fine. Maybe this has to do with reserved keywords which cannot be used as name of files